# NOR flash address lines

Tags: flash, flash-memories, nor-flash

I am wondering if someone can explain how the address lines work on NOR flash. Does each address line map to a physical area in flash? as in A0= 0000-FFFF if this is the case and the NOR has 21 address lines, how does it map the higher addresses? Or am i looking at this all wrong?

Comment: Do you know how to translate a binary number into some other base, like hex or decimal (if not, then fire up the calculator app on your PC and put it into "Programmer" mode). Now consider that all the address lines represent a binary number ...

Comment: Thankyou so much! sorry for the late reply but that made perfect sense.